# How to use the COM Object Method to rename the item in compressed/zip file

Tags: powershell

How do I rename the file inside the compressed file?

```
$timestamp = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).ToString('yyyy-MM')
$newFolderTimeStamp = (Get-Date).AddMonths(-1).ToString('MM - MMM-yyyy')
$sourceFile = "D:\Testing\1.txt","D:\Testing\2.txt","D:\Testing\3.txt","D:\Testing\4.txt","D:\Testing\5.txt"
#$sharedrive = "\\fs2\Backups\it\users.xlsx"
$newFolder = "D:\Testing\bin\$newFolderTimeStamp.zip"


######Compressed File
function Add-Zip
{
    param([string]$zipfilename)

    if(-NOT (test-path($zipfilename)))
    {
        #create an empty zip file
        set-content $zipfilename ("PK" + [char]5 + [char]6 + ("$([char]0)" * 18))
        
        #make sure it is not set to ReadOnly
        (dir $zipfilename).IsReadOnly = $false  
    }
    

    $shellApplication = new-object -com shell.application
    $zipPackage = $shellApplication.NameSpace($zipfilename)
    
    foreach($file in $input) 
    { 
            $zipPackage.CopyHere($file.FullName)
            Start-sleep -milliseconds 500
    }
}

######Get file for today's date
Get-ChildItem $sourceFile -Force | Where-Object{$_.LastWriteTime -gt $date -and $_.extension -ne ".zip"} | add-Zip $newFolder
```

Tried , but only rename the zip file name.

```
Get-ChildItem $sourceFile -Force | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Basename + '_' + $timestamp + $_.Extension } | Where-Object{$_.LastWriteTime -gt $date -and $_.extension -ne ".zip"} | add-Zip $newFolder
```

Expected result

06 - Jun-2019.zip

1_2019-06.txt

2_2019-06.txt

3_2019-06.txt

4_2019-06.txt

5_2019-06.txt

Comment: You cannot rename files in a zip archive using COM object without recompressing the archive. According to your code you're trying to rename source files before adding them to zip. Please state more clearly what is your issue.

Comment: @montonero your meaning, i just can rename the files before zip archive the files?

Comment: You already do this. This code should rename the files `Get-ChildItem $sourceFile -Force | Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Basename + '_' + $timestamp + $_.Extension }`. So I don't understand what is the issue.